# configure Laravel mix mix.webpackConfig({}) with entry points and outputs

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

I'm developing an application that use php 5.6 and laravel 5.4. I'm using laravel mix for build my assets. I need to know how to use mix.webpackConfig({}) method to use another webpack configurations like use babel-loader, riot-tag-loader etc. Is there any way to use this method to do that with entry point and output files? For an example, I need to do following thing inside my mix.webpackConfig({}).

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        admin: ['./resources/assets/admin/js/app.js'],
        'manuals/parent/child/js': ['./resources/views/manuals/parent/child/js/app.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]/app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tag$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'riot-tag-loader',
                query: {
                    type: 'es6',
                    hot: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Is that possible? Is that so, please let me know how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix is a configuration layer on top of [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), so to run your Mix tasks you only need to execute one of the NPM scripts that is included with the default Laravel package.json file: more details in official site

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix

Answer (score 1):

I've hardly found the laravel-mix `mix.webpackConfig({})` successfully initiated, and even working samples are rear. I do not know what framework you are trying to manage but this sample works; this is a config for less-loader, hope you can tune it to suit your purpose.

```
const path = require('path');
mix.webpackConfig({
 module: {
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader",
        exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node-modules"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/less"),
        ],
      },
  ]} 
})
```